# Safe to reference a C++ template type having a template parameter that's not compatible with the template?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

In the following code sample, I define a class DT (my default type) which I want to be able to pass as the parameter(s) for an arbitrary template.  In this example, I pass DT as the key and value parameters for std::map. I don't actually ever try to instantiate map<DT,DT>, I just want to use map<DT,DT> as the template parameter for a templatized function (in this sample, the function f()) that never actually references the type -- it's only used to produce a type-specific instance of the function.  (Note that you can't actually instantiate a std::map<DT,DT> since the key of a map must be comparable, but DT is not.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class DT {};

template <typename T>
string f() {
    return "foo";
}

int main() {
    cout << f<map<DT,DT>>() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This seems to work fine using g++.  I even tried passing DT for all four map parameters (overriding the default comparator, and allocator types).  Still works. But I'm worried that this technique might fail with some other template, or with some other compiler.  So my question is: **is this always safe for any template on any c++ compiler compliant with, say, the c++11 standard (and later standards).  In other words, is it always safe to pass a completely incompatible type as the parameter for a template, so long as you never try to instantiate that template?**

If you're wondering why on earth I'd want to do such a thing, I'm trying to setup a class where I can store type-dependent configuration strings.  It will have these two methods:

```
template<typename T>
const string& get<T>() const;

template<typename T>
void set<T>(const string& value);
```

I have it largely working to my satisfaction.  It has several nice features.  For example, types int, const int, int&, const int&, etc are all treated as the same type (which is what I want).  And you can store a configuration string for a base class that is later retrievable by a derived type if no entry is found for the more specific derived type.  But for the case of say, a std::map, I'd like to be able to store a default configuration string using type map<DT,DT> that will later be returned as a match for any map<Key,Value> when no entry is found for the specific map type at hand.  If the above code is valid, then I think I can produce the desired behavior.

Comment: I know this is language lawyer tagged, but why not use your own tag-type instead of `std::map`?

Comment: @super I don't understand the question. If the goal is to associate configuration with any possible type, then it needs to handle `std:;map`, too (since that is one of the possible types).

Comment: @melpomene The question states that a `std::map<DT, DT>` is incompatible in the sense that it could not actually be used, so I assumed it's purpose was to  tag `get/set` with a unique type.

Comment: @super, @melpomene:  yes, I just want to bind a config string to type `std::map<DT, DT>`, by calling `config.set<std::map<DT,DT>>("foo")`.  Then if someone invokes `config.get<std::map<int,int>>()` when no entry was previously stored for type `std::map<int,int>`, it would return the value stored for `std::map<DT,DT>`.  I could of course add `operator<()`, etc to make DT a valid key, but other template parameters on other templates might have other requirements I can't anticipate.

Comment: @MatthewBusche Out of curiosity, are your `get<>()` and `set<>()` methods wrapping access to a templetized singleton (strings), or are you dynamically expanding a given `Config` instance with instance-bound configuration strings based on invocations of `set<>()` and `get<>()` with different types?

Comment: @dfri It's dynamic.  There's an underlying support class that maps a type to a small generated integer.  (I saw no convenient way to use the standard typeinfo, so I generate my own type identifiers.)  I use that integer as the key in a map (though I may switch to a vector since I guarantee the numbers to be zero-based and consecutive).  The template stuff is still only in my head, so I'm not sure I can share how that will work with any reliability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I believe, the standard does not guarantee that `std::map<DT, DT>` will not be instantiated. [[temp.inst]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.spec#temp.inst-1) only specifies that

> Unless a class template specialization has been explicitly instantiated or explicitly specialized, the class template specialization is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context that requires a completely-defined object type or when the completeness of the class type affects the semantics of the program. […]

Note that this only tells us when a template is guaranteed to be instantiated, it does not give any guarantees that the template will not be instantiated if such an instantiation is not required. [[temp.inst]/10](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.spec#temp.inst-10) only gives such a guarantee for

> […] a function template, a variable template, a member template, a non-virtual member function, a member class, a static data member of a class template, or a substatement of a constexpr if statement ([stmt.if]), unless such instantiation is required. […]

Note the absence of class templates from this list. Thus, I believe, a compiler would theoretically be allowed to instantiate `std::map<DT, DT>` even thought it would not be necessary to do so. If instantiating the template `std::map` with `DT` as key and value type would be invalid, you'd have a problem. I am unable to find any guarantees concerning instantiating `std::map` with a key type that does not support a comparison operator. While I would expect this to just work with basically any implementation, I do think that an implementation would theoretically be allowed to, e.g., have a `static_assert` that checks whether the key type does fulfill the necessary requirements. [[res.on.functions]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/constraints#res.on.functions-1) would seem to apply (emphasis mine):

> In certain cases (replacement functions, handler functions, operations on types used to instantiate standard library template components), the C++ standard library depends on components supplied by a C++ program. **If these components do not meet their requirements, the Standard places no requirements on the implementation.**

Thus, I think that, strictly speaking, the standard does not guarantee that using `std::map<DT, DT>` will work…

If you simply want to use `std::map<DT, DT>` as a sort of tag type to indicate a special case, I would suggest to just not use `std::map` but something else, for example:

```
template <typename, typename>
struct default_config_tag;
```

and then `default_config_tag<DT, DT>` or just `DT` as your tag (not sure if you need the argument to be an instance of a template with two type parameters) should be sufficient…

Comment: I thought about that, but I want different default values for map and multimap, etc.  There are other approaches I could take, but it would be nice if I could set the default value for a map using the same kind of template as I do for specific types.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response.  I may forge ahead with my bad idea to see if I can at least get the thing working.  Later I can try to redesign the interface to avoid this potential problem.

Comment: @MatthewBusche what you're trying to do here seems generally quite complicated to me. I'm not sure what exactly your goal is with this, but I would think that there must be a much simpler way to get there. Probably would require a quite different approach to the whole problem though…but not much more can be said without knowing what the actual problem is…

Comment: Detailing the whole problem would be inappropriate for this forum.  I'm not ready to share it anyway.  As far as my config class goes, it's so far only about 150 lines of code -- so not complicated at all.  But I haven't put in this template stuff yet.  In general, that could get complicated if I wanted to take it to the nth degree -- supporting partial default settings for `map<DT,int>` and `map<int,DT>`.  Or even worse settings for `map<int,list<DT>>`, etc.  But I don't intend to provide such fine control -- at least not initially.

Comment: @MatthewBusche I would just generally question whether you really need to support `std::` containers as config values. If you want a sort of recursive/tree-like config structure, why not just allow a config node to contain other config nodes? Then you just need default values for whatever types are allowed as values as well as a default config node and your problem should be solved!? At least, I've been doing it like this for many years and it has not failed me yet…

Comment: A template parameter isn't a context where a complete type is required, `std::map<DT, DT>` isn't instantiated as a result.

Comment: @PasserBy I could not find anything in the standard that guarantees that a class template is not instantiated if a complete type is not required. As far as I'm aware (as explained above), the standard only guarantees that a class template will be instantiated if a complete type is required. But from that doesn't follow that it will not be instantiated if it's not required. If you can point me to the respective paragraph that would say otherwise, I'd be really happy to know…

Comment: @MichaelKenzel I'm looking things up, but your reasoning doesn't quite add up. The rules on instantiations are otherwise pointless, the compiler might as well instantiate everything anywhere.

Comment: @PasserBy As also noted above, the standard gives explicit guarantees concerning situations where templates must not be instantiated (e.g., definitions of member functions of class templates) unless required. Class templates, however, do not seem fall into any of the categories there…

Comment: @MichaelKenzel Yes I realize that, and I think there should be a reason for that. According to your reasoning, CRTP is plain broken, and the rules of points of instantiation are all pointless.

Comment: @PasserBy I don't see how the curiously recurring template pattern would be affected by this. Inheritance requires a complete type!? The rules for points of instantiation are mainly relevant to name lookup. They have nothing to do with *when* something is instantiated but with *where* the instantiation logically lives if it is!?

Comment: @PasserBy after thinking about it some more, I'm not sure anymore; maybe it is indeed supposed to mean that they must not be instantiated if a complete type is not required. I find it very confusing, however, that there would be a need to explicitly state in which cases templates must not instantiated if the intent of the preceding paragraphs was to list the only cases in which instantiation may happen. Because the cases that are then listed as "must not instantiate" are already not part of the list of cases that cause instantiation…

Answer (score 0):

You've already [got the answer to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55888899/4573247), but the context of the question is likewise interesting for readers of this post, so I thought it'd be valuable to mention that you may use tag dispatching for a use case such as your own, to:

- Set up default configuration strings, at compile time, for specific types (e.g. `int`) or groups of types (e.g. `std::map<K, V>` for generic `K` and `V`)

Without tag dispatching, this can be tricky as you may not partially specialize a function template.

E.g.:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Config {
 public:
  static const std::string& get() { return Config::getString(); }

  static void set(const std::string& value) { Config::getString() = value; }

  Config(Config const&) = delete;
  void operator=(Config const&) = delete;

 private:
  static std::string& getString() {
    static std::string s(defaultString(dispatch_tag<T>{}));
    return s;
  }

  template <typename U>
  struct dispatch_tag {};

  // Default string unless specified for specific types below.
  template <typename U = T>
  static constexpr std::string_view defaultString(dispatch_tag<U>) {
    return "default";
  }

  // Default config strings for a select number of types.
  static constexpr std::string_view defaultString(dispatch_tag<int>) {
    return "default int";
  }

  template <typename K, typename V>
  static constexpr std::string_view defaultString(
      dispatch_tag<std::map<K, V>>) {
    return "default map";
  }
};

int main() {
  std::cout << Config<int>::get() << "\n";                 // default int
  std::cout << Config<std::string>::get() << "\n";         // default
  std::cout << Config<std::map<int, int>>::get() << "\n";  // default map

  Config<int>::set("custom int");
  Config<std::map<int, int>>::set("custom int-int map");

  std::cout << Config<int>::get() << "\n";                  // custom int
  std::cout << Config<std::map<int, int>>::get() << "\n";   // custom int-int map
  std::cout << Config<std::map<int, char>>::get() << "\n";  // default map
}
```

This does not solve, however, that you would like to (based on your comments to your own post) specify, at run-time, the value of the fall-back default configuration string for generic types (say, `std::map<K, V>`).